# Angular 2 HttpClient error body

Tags: ajax, angular, rest

I'm using the new (4.3) HttpClient in angular to POST data to my backend server:

```
this.httpClient.post<View>(`/path`, data).subscribe(
  (view: View) => console.log("Success"),
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(error)
      this.errorMessage = <any>error.error;
  });
);
```

This call generates an (expected) error (409), but for some reason, the logged error does not contain the body of the error sent from the server. I can see the status code, but the `error.error` field, which should contain the response body is missing. Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

I've tested the backend call using curl, and can see the response body from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in angular which is throwing an exception during the json parsing and not populating the error field:

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18466

Answer (score 0):

Is your error body coming back as JSON or un-formatted text/other?  I had a similar problem until i realized the body returned with the error result was a simple string.  I had to change the call to something similar to this (forgive the lack of type-safety here):

```
this.http.post('http://address', body, { responseType: 'text' })
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.result = data['value'];
            this.router.navigate(['/route']);
        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.error = error.error;
            this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        });
```

Comment: Is this using the new HttpClient? When I use that syntax, I get the error: `TS2345: Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.`

Comment: @DanielScott See https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

{responseType: 'text'} goes to body parameter, just after the url.